Log level for Azure health check function
The Azure health check function is spamming our ApplicationInsights storage and therefore causing charges for ingestion.
The FunctionStarted and FunctionCompleted messages outnumber real messages by a factor of about 10.
How can we turn them off?
It's a C# web app running in an App Service Plan.
In the menu at the left of the app service plan page in Azure, in the Monitoring section there is an item called Health Check that looks like this:

And here's how I've implemented it:
                .Use(async (HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next) =>
                {
                    if (context.Request.Path == "/api/health")
                    {
                        return;
                    }

Consequently ApplicationInsights gets spammed with messages

from the C# web app that responds to the /api/health requests (which is easy to turn off), and
from the thing inside Azure that triggers the requests -- seems to be an Azure function.

Disabling logging for a function*
The documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json implies that it's possible to turn off logging for a function.
None of these are working -- still getting spammed. Any idea how to do it?
  "logging": {
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Trace",
      "System": "Warning",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Namespace.CalculationsService.Functions.HealthFunction": "Warning",
      "Namespace.CalculationsService.Functions.HealthFunction.Health": "Warning",
      "Functions.Health": "Warning",
      "Function.Health": "Warning",
      "Health": "Warning"
    },


It is a function app or Web App? Can you please share your .csproj file?

Please share the spam messages.. Share the screenshot of Application Insights Transaction search.

Please share your .csproj file once.
